# { $t: "", $v: ""} structure in MongoDB collections using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using pymongo libraries to upload my data into documentDB (it accepts MongoDB libraries). 
My json data objects (read using the json library from a json file) before sending them to my documentDB collection are in the format of (a portion of the data):

```
...
{
"id": [
    "{}",
    "i"
  ]
}
...
```

However, in the database they are stored like:

```
...
{
  "id": {
    "$t": 4,
    "$v": [
      {
        "$t": 2,
        "$v": "{}"
      },
      {
        "$t": 2,
        "$v": "i"
      }
    ]
  }
}
...
```

My python code that inserts data into MongoDB is

```
client = MongoClient("url")
self.__db = client["database"]
self.__db["collection"].insert_one(data)
```

For debugging purposes I added this line right before insert_one() statement

```
for k, v in data.items():
  print(k, v)
```

and here is the output on the console:

```
.. 
id ['{}', 'i'] 
..
```

Is there any additional parameter that I need to set on pymongo to save data as is?
When I read data from the MongoDB using pymongo it handles $t, $v conversions but my data readers are not in python and don't do the conversion automatically

**Update**
I switched to DocumentDb python library. It works just fine. 
I just needed to spend a couple of hours creating a new db interface for it in my app.

Comment: Please clarify which one you are using, [DocumentDB](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/) or [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/) ? They are not the same database.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, but failed that I could not get the same json structure like yours on DocumentDB for MongoDB API. Please update your  class code for `data` to help me reproduce the issue. And I don't know whether you have implemented `__iter__(self)` method for the `data` class which can help converting object to dict via `dict(object)` because pymongo need to insert data which must be an instance of dict, bson, or or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping.

Comment: @WanBachtiar I'm using MongoDB libraries to talk to DocumentDB.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I'm reading a json file and sending them on the fly to pymongo. I updated the question with iterator info

Comment: I Have the same problem reading with node.js... does it has something to do with BSON? not quite sure if it does.
Could you fix it?

Comment: Using 1.x DocumentDB Libs this problem looks like it is part of Document DB.  If you directly myDocument.ToString() you get this type and value response with $t  and $v   It is like a schema and Value in a JSON Doc that the DocuemntDB Libs or Infrastructure gives back and is using internally ?   I do not think this has to do with pymongo.  OR is this what it looks like if you use a true Mongo lib to upload to DocumentDB ?