# pymongo insert_one document structure is lost

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a Python3 application which inserts movie information into a mongodb back-end (MongoDB Compass), and a separate nodejs application which returns it.
this was working fine, however i cleared the DB out and re-ran the application, now when I insert a document with `insert_one` the structure returned is always lost:

`query = {
  "Name": name,
  "Year": year,
  "Format": definition,
  "Extension": extension,
  "Filepath": filepath,
  "MD5Hash": filehash,
  "Subtitles": subtitles,
  "Date": date,
  "FileSize": size
}
result = db.Movies_test.insert_one(query)`

first run returned data:

`_id: 5b1470da91cb5a2240c57c43
Extension: "mkv"
Format: "1080p"
Filepath: "E:\Movies\10 Cloverfield Lane [2016] 1080p.mkv"
Year: "2016"
FileSize: 2953397031
MD5Hash: "baf1b857c3f2f4fe6d08161e814a64c2"
Date: 2018-06-03 23:51:06.503
Subtitles: false
Name: "10 Cloverfield Lane"
UpdateTime: 2018-06-04 00:42:51.141`

second run returned data:

`_id: 5b80322f91cb5a05a809a70f
Year: "2016"
FileSize: 2953397031
Format: "1080p"
Filepath: "E:\Movies\10 Cloverfield Lane [2016] 1080p.mkv"
Date: 2018-08-24 17:28:31.067
Name: "10 Cloverfield Lane"
Extension: "mkv"
MD5Hash: ""
Subtitles: false`

I noticed a similar question here: [{ $t: “”, $v: “”} structure in MongoDB collections using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670909/t-v-structure-in-mongodb-collections-using-pymongo) however there is no solution, the user just switched to using DocumentDB.

I read that `insert` has an extra option `insert(query, {'ordered': True})`, but this also does not keep the data structure:

`_id: 5b80373691cb5a10c42c5906
Subtitles: false
Format: "1080p"
FileSize: 2953397031
Extension: "mkv"
Date: 2018-08-24 17:49:58.160
Name: "10 Cloverfield Lane"
MD5Hash: ""
Filepath: "E:\Movies\10 Cloverfield Lane [2016] 1080p.mkv"
Year: "2016"`

Any help would be great, and ideally I would prefer to insert in the original query order, instead of processing the output when its comes out of nodejs.

Comment: Why is the order for the document fields important here?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule  as stated, the returned document is appended to a table, ideally I'd like to keep the structure the same so I don't have to rebuild the tables each time (as I said, when I destroyed the db and rebuilt it, the structure changes). I managed to work around by rebuilding the query before appending to the table but I would prefer not to have to do this.

Comment: AFAICT, mongo python driver predictably returns document fields ordered as they were written. I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior using pymongo. I think that this issue here may be with the node driver.

Comment: Strange, my python insert_one query ran the same each time but produced different structures within mongo compass, so i don't think it's a nodeJs issue. Can you confirm that running an insert query, destroying that database and re running produces the same structure each time?  As it doesn't for me!

Comment: I tried it and made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/osule/6c09b8d0e21bd1889da06a9e5f4e38fe). Unfortunately, I didnt get the same results as you did. Maybe you want to look in how compass presents the results.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I tried your gist, works fine for me too... I just noticed the hash on the 1st set of returned data I posted. I remember now I have a second hashing function that hashes and adds a updateTime field. I'm wondering if this is actually modified the document structure as well. My bad! But to sum up, the documents keep the structure during insertion by default?

Comment: Maybe you can share the hashing function in your question and we can figure out whether it causes this effect. To answer your question about ordering, there isn't a lot of tests to show it to be true everytime that field ordering is preserved. I'm guessing that since dictionaries keep the field ordering in python3, this should be the case.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule  so the relevant line would be `result = db.Movies.find_one_and_update({"_id": document['_id']},
                                                   {"$set": {"MD5Hash": md5, "UpdateTime": update_time}},
                                                   return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)`. I'm not seeing anything that would alter the structure. My fix was to edit the statement in node before sending it back to the table, this isn't so bad. But still, would be nice to know what the deal is!